# Universe DB Connection via SSH

Tags: universe, u2, rocket-u2

How can I connect the universe database via SSH (using putty).
Is there any way to query universe database via ssh .
we need to pull records from universe database using ssh (i.e.., putty).

Please help..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If sshd is configured on the server, the difference between the shell that it returns to you on authentication is functionally the same as it would be if you used telnet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can cobble together a solution using the built in `UVread` command. There is almost no documentation for it, but it allows you to do a read of a record from the UNIX shell. On my system the `UVread` executable binary was installed under `/u2/uv/bin/UVread`.

For example:

> `./UVread /u2/eclipse/ENTITY 1234`

In this case, ENTITY was the name of the `VOC` file, and `1234` is the record ID. This will output the record with the Attribute/Value/Subvalue marks present, so you can then parse the data.

https://www.mail-archive.com/u2-users@listserver.u2ug.org/msg32636.html
http://u2-universe-unidata.1073795.n5.nabble.com/UV-commands-from-Unix-td11471.html